# Jquery selector for "has attribute and parent isn't selected"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a jquery selector that says something like, "has attribute=x and parent hasn't been selected yet"?  In the code below, node 1-1 gets added twice to the lower div, but I only want it to be added as part of node 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/XLU4W/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this:  http://jsfiddle.net/JesseAldridge/XLU4W/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something like:

```
var result = $('div[mod_date="1"]');

result.filter(function (i) {
  if(result.has(this.parentNode))
     return false;
  else
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try in this way...

```
var html = $('div[mod_date="1"]').parent().html()

$('.selection').append(html);
```

[**See here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aZZeV/)

Comment: This results in node 0 in the selection div, which has mod_date="0".  Not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly a selector you described but matching only the first level, you could do:

```
$('.main > div[mod_date="1"]').clone().appendTo($('.selection'))
```

Comment: In my real use case, matching nodes can be at an arbitrary depth.  I guess walking the tree is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should do the job:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZrjkD/